# Add a Value Automatically to a Cell Based on Another Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a value to a cell based on another with VBA but I'm not sure how. I already searched on internet about it but can't find anything.

I have a table, and on the Column C, if any cell contains the text "MAM" (because it might have MAM-565), then change the value from Cell A to "Wrong", but if it contains "NAC", then change value to "Correct". It should be in the same row as the text found.

Also, I want to add the date automatically to cell E every time Cell in D is filled.
This the code I have already:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Add Issue Type'
Dim Code As Range
Set Code = Range("C2:C100000")

For Each Cell In Code
If InStr(1, Cell, "NAC") Then
Range("A2:A10000").Value = "Correct"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cell, "MAM") Then
Range("A2:A10000").Value = "Wrong"

End If
Next

End Sub
```

This how my table looks like:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN58Z.png)

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: To me it sounds like you want the `Change` event, not the `SelectionChange` event?

Comment: That sounds like at minimum two seperate issues. Problem A) Check cell in Column C and change Column A (same row) accordingly and Problem B) Add Date to Column E on change of Column D. Those should be two separate threads in that case. Also, I don't see a question/specific issue, just a request for code. I'm no professional, but the code you posted doesn't look like it would do anything remotley close to what you are attempting. Can you break this issue down further and remove unneccessary code? See --> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you want to check all of column C every time that there is a change in Column D?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I though it would be only one since it might need the same code. But I want to add a value on cell A depending on the text on cell C.

Comment: @BigBen Well, I don't know too much about events, but searching out on internet, it might help, though I don't know what code to add.

Comment: It comes down to - do you want this code to run when cell(s) value(s) *change*, or when different cells are *selected*?

Comment: As @BigBen said, from your description it sounds like you want the `Change` event instead of `SelectionChange`. But the code you provided does not even make an attempt to add a date, nor does it make an attempt to fulfill your first statement of needing to conditionally modify Column A's value.

Comment: @BigBen When cell value changes

Comment: @jclasley Let me show the code I'm trying to do...

Comment: Is changing the code from NAC to "Correct" a one-time thing, or should that always be done automatically?

Comment: @BigBen, it reads to me that he wants to change the value of "A1" (arbitrary row assignment) to either "Correct" or "Wrong" depending on the value of "C1" (arbitrary row assignment). Dark161000 please clarify

Comment: @BigBen Yes, I want that to always be done automatically. I though there is a way to do it without using formulas because I'm not sure if I'll use the 100,000 rows. It's a file that multiple users will use. Every time I click on a cell from Column D, our usernames will appear, and after that I want the date to appear on the next Cell on Column E automatically.

Comment: If your data is formatted as a table (Ctrl+T), then you could easily use a formula for this and not worry about VBA, plus Excel will fill the formula down if you add rows.

Comment: @jclasley That's it, I want that to be done automatically. Since it's a table, it will be filling the row with the color format, otherwise, If I use formula, I need to add a bigger table with 100,000 rows

Comment: @BigBen I didn't know that, I will try that then. Thanks :). From your code, It's not doing anything... am I missing something?

Comment: @Dark161000 - sorry I had a `Not` that shouldn't have been in there, edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically add the datestamp:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)      
    Dim rng as Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim cell as Range
    For Each cell in rng
         If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then ' don't do anything if cell was cleared
             cell.Offset(,1).Value = Date
         End If
    Next

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

As far as the Correct/Wrong, this can easily be done with a formula `(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...))`. I don't see the need for VBA here.

Even better, create a table using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. Excel will automatically add the formula in column A in new rows.

Comment: Great! I made a slight edit to not add the datestamp if the cell was cleared... ignore the edit if that's not what you want.